# urllib2.urlopen(): getting the size of the content

Tags: python, urllib2

Still working my way round python whenever work permits it...

I'm querying a load of internal webUI's using a script that uses `urllib2.urlopen`. I'm wondering how it is possible to get the size of the page content from each request. I can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks in advance,

MHibbin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
print len(urlopen(url).read())
```

or

```
>>> result = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.spiegel.de')
>>> result.headers['content-length']
'181291'
```

Comment: For size of the content, `urlopen(url).read().__sizeof__()` works too.

Comment: Also, this will exhaust the resource that has `read()` called on it. If you need both the response's `read()` result as well as its size, be sure to call both, and not in one operation as done here.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, the second one **should** be faster as you don't have to read the resource, and indeed, it does not exhaust the resource.